# Best "Keep your music with you" setup

Tags: sync, music

I really enjoy listening to music, and because of this I have a lot of sources for it. This is not always a good thing since I have my music stored on a lot of devices ( home computer, work computer, online storage, iPod ) and sometimes its a bit difficult to have the same music in all places.
Sometimes I don't have the same songs in all the places, I make a playlist in one place and want it in the other place etc.

How do you keep your music in sync on all your devices.

PS: I use both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I should mention [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) -- a cloud file storage service with clients for Linux, Windows, Mac and iPhone. If you have a lot of music, though, you might have to opt for a paid plan (you only get 2GB free). It's a great service, though.

Comment: +1 always vote dropbox up. it's amazing what they do to keep files properly in sync across many different file partitions and OS'es.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I keep it all on my home computer, and ensure I've always got a good selection on my music player, that way I have always have the music I want to listen to in my pocket.

No need to copy it to my work computer. (not to mention the legal issues that might arise from doing this).

Comment: i think there were a few discussions about the legal part, and the conclusion was that it was legal, since you don't distribute it you just store it in more then one place, but you are the only one that listens to it.

Comment: I tend to agree, and personally I wouldn't worry about it, however I was thinking more from the company's perspective to be honest, as many companies will claim rights to any data stored on their network. Bit of a grey area IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I have one master copy of my music on my home PC. I sync my entire music collection to my portable music player for listening to my music in the car, while I travel, etc. When at the office, I listen to my music online.

I have used several services in the past. MP3 Tunes (http://www.mp3tunes.com/) allows you to upload your collection to their site and access it anywhere with a web browser. The same thing can be done with Lala (http://www.lala.com/). The trouble with MP3 Tunes and Lala is that you have to upload everything before you can listen and it takes a long time.

MY current solution is using a site called Orb (http://orb.com/). You install Orb on your home PC and you can access all of its media from the web.

Orb is nice because it instantly reflects any changes you make to you collection. Orb even has clients for mobile phones and gaming devices. The down side is that you must keep your PC on all the time.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Buy an external hard disk. Use your main home pc as a master. Install [toucan](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/toucan) on your external hard drive, and always sync your master pc music collection with the external drive.